# ¿Como cambio el metodo de encriptado de contraseña en Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, contraseña

tengo esta situación, tengo una tabla existente en donde se almacena el Nombre de usuario y Contraseña llamada "SysUsers", pero la contraseña esta almacenada encriptada con md5, y laravel encripta en bcrypt. Entonces necesito cambiar el metodo para que cuando compare las contras den correctas cuando lo sean.

Archivo: auth.php

```
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'md5',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],
    'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'md5',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'md5' => [
        'driver' => 'md5',
        'providers' => 'users',
    ],
],
'providers' => [
    // 'users' => [
    //     'driver' => 'eloquent',
    //     'model' => App\Models\User::class,
    // ],

    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'database',
        'table' => 'SysUsers',
        'username' => 'Usuario',
        'password' => [
            'hash' => true,
            'provider' => 'users',
            'field' => 'Password',
        ],
    ],
],
```

Archivo hashing.php

```
    'driver' => 'md5',
```

Y este es el error que me envia LARAVEL al colocar en mi formulario el usuario y contraseña

> Auth driver [md5] for guard [md5] is not defined.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Es que no hay un driver md5, tendrías que hacerlo tu, o buscar otra manera, como hacer el login manualmente. Pero antes agotaría las posibilidades de abandonar md5 en favor de bcrypt, se puede hacer de a poco de forma transparente para el usuario

Comment: Recuerda que no se recomienda usar md5 para el hash de contraseñas (https://www.php.net/manual/es/faq.passwords.php#faq.passwords.fasthash). Como menciona @porloscerros, el cambio puede hacerse de forma transparente para el usuario.

Comment: Oh entiendo, y es que a fuerza tengo que usar md5, porque tengo que usar esa tabla que tiene en md5 las contras. Ya estoy investigando sobre cómo crear el driver y bueno a ver si queda. Si saben algo que me pueda ayudar con eso se los agradezco.